# jquery multiple show/hide buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I am trying to convert a lot of JavaScript to jQuery and I have a task that I believe has a simple jQuery shortcut, but I don't know what it is and I haven't been able to find an example.

I have a page with many toggled divs. They are in the form that follows where ### is a unique integer for each pair.

```
<button class='togglebutton' onclick="toggle('div###');">+</button>
<div id='div###'>...some text...</div>
```

I'd assume the shortcut is something like:

```
$('.togglebutton').onclick(function() {
    var divid = '#div'+?????;
    $(divid).toggle();
});
```

My theory... if I give each button an id, such as 'button###', then I can use substring to get the value after the word 'button', something like:

```
$(this).id().substring(6,3);
```

Obviously, that didn't work. So, I figured that I should ask if there is a simple shortcut in jQuery to pair a showhide button with a separate div.

Comment: Are the buttons and divs always directly next to each other in the source code? Then it's as easy as `$(this).next().toggle()`...

Comment: Why don't you assign some class attribute and use that as a selector get all divs you want to hide ?

Comment: @MaheshChavda I only want to show/hide one div per button. Each div has an associated button next to it.

Comment: Use `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `$(this).id()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to do this no matter where your div locates http://jsfiddle.net/tg5op333/25/  
HTML

```
    <button class='togglebutton' data-id="1">+</button>
    <div id='1' style="display:none">...some text...</div>
    <button class='togglebutton' data-id="2">+</button>
    <div id='2' style="display:none">...some text...</div>
    <button class='togglebutton' data-id="3">+</button>
    <div id='3' style="display:none">...some text...</div>
    <button class='togglebutton' data-id="4">+</button>
    <div id='4' style="display:none">...some text...</div>
```

JS:

```
  $('.togglebutton').click(function() {
        $("#"+ $(this).data('id')).toggle();
    });
```

Comment: That is very useful. It will ensure nobody comes in behind me and breaks the toggles by moving elements around.

Comment: Correct ! . You can style your HTML in a better way to be consistence for every toggle

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML is ordered like you show in your question, then use:

```
$('.togglebutton').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```js
$('.togglebutton').click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='togglebutton'>+</button>
<div id='div1'>...some text...</div>
<button class='togglebutton'>+</button>
<div id='div2'>...some text...</div>
<button class='togglebutton'>+</button>
<div id='div3'>...some text...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. While the actual code has the button separated from the div, I think I can shuffle things around. Trying now...

Comment: If you update your question with the actual HTML structure I can update my answer for you so you don't have to alter the content.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1) You can use some common class attribute to all dives and select all using that.

Or

2) Or else you can use this wildcard selector :

```
$("[id^=div]")
```

It gives you all divs whose id starts with div.