# hide first button onclick show second , hide second onclick show first button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have two buttons: Approve & Reject  (submit button )

Upon clicking Approve, I want to hide that button. Reject button will then appear. 
If reject is clicked after Approve then the opposite should happen and I need to show the Approve button again.

Note:

Both buttons should be there before doing anything.
I want to update database status on click so please provide me good advise.

I have some code in place but it is not working as expected, because the page is refreshing when updating entries

Comment: Hints: (1) Use AJAX to update the database without reloading the page - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20404407/2298301) for example. (2) jQuery [toggle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36362067/2298301) could be of some help in hiding and showing the buttons in a cyclic order.

Comment: Grammar. Spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothin fancy...

```
<html>
<script>

function hideAccept(){
document.getElementById("acceptMe").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("rejectMe").style.display="block";
 }

function hideReject(){
document.getElementById("rejectMe").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("acceptMe").style.display="block";
 }

</script>

<button id="acceptMe" onclick="hideAccept()">Accept</button>
<button id="rejectMe" onclick="hideReject()">Reject</button>

</html>
```

Comment: yes vbudo  i tried it in different file & it is working there but don't know why it is not working in my code i think page is refreshing